# how to do 'knife ec2 server create' from python script

Tags: python, chef-infra, knife, amazon-ec2

I am trying to convert my ant script to python. The ant script runs knife ec2 server create command. 
What is the best practice to run knife ec2 server create from Python?

BTW, is python the right scripting technology for automation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with a Python interface for knife, but I see no reason for this not to work:

```
import sh

sh.knife.ec2.server.create(r='role[x]', I='ami-xxxxxxx', f='t2.micro', aws-access-key-id=ACCESS_KEY, aws-secret-access-key=SECRET_KEY)
```

You'll need to `pip install sh` for it, so you can also use subprocess for it instead if you don't want extra dependencies:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen('knife ec2 server create ...', shell=True)
```

If I were you, i'd write a small client for running knife commands more comfortably though, as if you use knife, this is probably not the only command you're going to run. `sh` would be ideal for that.

Regarding your second question, you should open another issue for it.